# Django: I have extended group model, how to make queries to get field value?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have extended the group model as the following:

```
class MyGroup(ProfileGroup):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    c_annotates = models.ManyToManyField(Annotation, verbose_name=_('annotation'), blank=True, null=True)
    c_locations = models.ManyToManyField(Location, verbose_name=_('locations'), blank=True, null=True)
    date_begin = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('date begin'), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    date_end = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('date end'), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

Now the group in database has new attributes like date_begin and date_end. Now I am wondering how can I get the value of date_begin and date_end in the views.py from the corresponding entry of the database? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the database to get the model you want:

```
obj = MyGroup.objects.get(id=...)
```

After that you can access the values (as they are in the database) by doing:

```
date_begin = obj.date_begin
date_end = obj.date_end
```